# Edit Jquery UI Accordion icon color

Tags: jquery, user-interface, colors, icons, accordion

I was just wondering whether I could edit the color of the default icon of this accordion, keeping it black, even when it is expanded. I was just looking for a practical solution that does not require rebuilding a new accordion or uploading a custom icon.

my code here: https://jsfiddle.net/d4riog7/5ucxwa00/

not sure it can be achieved within the function:

```
 $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      [...]
    });
```

or even via CSS

```
#accordion .ui-icon{
   [...]
}
```

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/zwqtb98m/)

Use background image.

```
.ui-icon
{
    background-image: url(http://download.jqueryui.com/themeroller/images/ui-icons_black_256x240.png) !important;
}
```

You can download the icon png file in any color you like. Just change the color part in the following url:

```
http://download.jqueryui.com/themeroller/images/ui-icons_*COLOR*_256x240.png
```

Or download and save locally and use locall URL.

Comment: Thank you, I reckon this is the best solution other than uploading a custom icon that perhaps would require more work on styling.

Answer (score 0):

It is not perfect, but see what happen when you add this style rule to your fiddle:

```
.ui-icon:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0,255,255, 0.5);
  transition: all .3s linear;
}
```

Unfortunately, the icon it's a `span` with background, so no much room to change the image but with previous answer. My solutions gives a tint to the entire span.

Comment: thank you, unfortunately giving tint to the entire span is probably too much for what I'd like to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the down arrow like using the below code.

```
.ui-state-active .ui-icon {
    background-image: url("https://download.jqueryui.com/themeroller/images/ui-icons_444444_256x240.png");
}
```